# Web3.js getPastLogs() fromBlock error

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, logs

I am trying to get some logs from ropsten and here is my code:

```
web3.eth.getPastLogs(
  {
    address: '0x3b873a919aa0512d5a0f09e6dcceaa4a6727fafe',
    fromBlock: 3292448,
    toBlock: 3292448,
  },
).then(console.log).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

which results in error:

```
Error: Returned error: invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to Hex:

```
fromBlock: web3.utils.toHex(3292448)
toBlock: web3.utils.toHex(3292448)
```